# Creating a database connection for my project will either produce a generic error or give no confirmation at all

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, oracle11gr2

I'm ultimately trying to sync a change with the database onto an entity. I went to the database navigator in JDeveloper 11g and right clicked one of the projects and selected New Connection. The dialog appeared and I entered my info. I clicked test and it worked.

[image]

But when I try to click OK, I get a generic error. And I click OK again, it tells me the connection has already been created with that name. But it of course doesn't. refreshing the connections shows nothing. Error:

> Performing action (744) New Connection [ from NavWindow ] [ for (
>   EntDataMaint, EntDataMaintUI.jpr, EntDataMaint.jws ) ]
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: message is null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: message is null
>   o.javatools.dialogs.MessagePanel.setMessage(MessagePanel.java:213)
>   o.javatools.dialogs.BaseMessageDialog.setMessage(BaseMessageDialog.java:186)
>   o.javatools.dialogs.MessageDialog.runDialog(MessageDialog.java:166)
>   o.javatools.dialogs.MessageDialog.runDialog(MessageDialog.java:210)
>   o.javatools.dialogs.MessageDialog.error(MessageDialog.java:239)

Comment: What DB version do you try to connect to?

Comment: @TimoHahn Oracle 11 G - 11.2.0.4.0